# Vertical aligment elements in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

i'm create a little site like a app store page, and cant align all elements in the middle of div .game-dark

```
<div class="row">
<div class="game-dark col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
        <div class="number col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <img src="img/kings-empire.png" alt="Kings Empire" title="Kings Empire" class="thumb img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-5">
        <h2 class="game-name">Kings Empire</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Скачать</button>
        </div>

</div>
```

How i can vertical align all elements in the middle in my case?

Live example - [here](http://mellowkids.ru/ios6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to realize this.

here a simple way:

add this to your css

```
.game-dark {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

no margin on `<p>`

```
.number p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

set max-height to the img

```
.img-responsive {
  min-height: 45px;
  min-width: 45px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

remove margin/padding of `h2`

```
h2.game-name {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100px
}
```

more ways are here http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: All fixed, except image - max-height: 100px; - maybe line-height? Anyway doesnt work for image.

Answer (score 1):

First set `line-height` to `98px` on `.game-dark.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12`, and remove `display: block` style from image. That will align everything except second to last div. With `h2` set top and bottom margin to 0, and also set `line-height` to `98px`.